# angularjs $sce is undefined, using angularjs 1.65

Tags: angularjs

i am using angularjs 1.65 version
and its seems that $sce is getting me undefined 
i have been trying serval times to get it fixed over 3 hours on it.

here is the module :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngclipboard','oitozero.ngSweetAlert']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {})
```

and here is the controller :

```
 app.controller('monitormainController',
 ['$rootScope','$scope','$timeout','SweetAlert','$sce',  function
 ($scope,$timeout,$rootScope,$watch,SweetAlert,$sce) {

  $scope.copyset = function(name){ $scope.trustedHtml =
  $sce.trustAsHtml(name); };

 });
```

i am getting an error which says $sce is undefined

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (File not found) angular.js:14642 TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'trustAsHtml' of undefined
>       at Scope.$scope.copyset (monitormainController.js:93)
>       at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15500), :4:153)
>       at callback (angular.js:27285)
>       at Scope.$eval (angular.js:18372)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18472)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:27290)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5095)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4766)

will be happy to get any answer thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependencies are in the wrong order here.  You must match the order of the dependencies in the array exactly with the parameters in the function.  Also, you are expecting `$watch` in your function, but not including it in the dependency list.

**Edit**:  If you are intending to use `$scope.$watch` rather than a `$watch` service that you created or installed, that isn't an injectable service.  Therefore, it should not be passed as a function parameter.

Instead of:

```
['$rootScope','$scope','$timeout','SweetAlert','$sce',  function
($scope,$timeout,$rootScope,$watch,SweetAlert,$sce) {
```

Try:

```
['$rootScope','$scope','$timeout','SweetAlert','$sce',  function
($rootScope,$scope, $timeout, SweetAlert, $sce) {
```

Comment: Still not working :( , changed the way you did .
its kind of wired . idk how to say it even,
all seems to be okay for that.

Comment: angularjs when you install scope are giving you the $watch. from what i have read.

Comment: I updated the answer;  more than likely, you were expecting to use `$scope.$watch` rather than some `$watch` service.  removing that should make any errors related to it go away.